# use list.phtml from auction extension on catalog page instead of custom template list.phtml

Tags: magento, templates

We have magento community webshop with a template that we bought. all things works fine. Now we bought an auction extension from magestore and are testing it. Problem we have right now is that it shows fine on the product page, but not on de catalog product page. one way or another it comes up with the `list.phtml` of the bought template and not with the options of the plugin `list.phtml`? how can we change this, so the plugin 'template' shows the right list.phtml file?

Extension location:

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/auction
```

Template location:

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/ma_megashop/template/catalog/product
```

*** EDIT *

Thx for your reply. But when i make a template update in de admin control panel, My products 
are disapeared. I just wanna have the timer in de catalog product view instead of the price-box and discription rules beneath the product photo. So it picks up the other list.phtml i think only my products on that page are gone after the update of that category template in the backend.

I also got an error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getLastBid() on a non-object in .../app/design/frontend/default/default/template/auction/list.phtml on line 22

Answer (score 0):

You can probably tighten up which .phtml to use by specifying it explicitly in your theme's local.xml file. If you know how to do this, great, go ahead. If you don't know how to do this can you tell us the URL of both the 'product page' and the 'catalog product page' - we don't need to see your full URL, just everything after the top level domain because I can't work out what page (ie route) 'catalog product page' means so I can't tell you the XML .

You may also want to check your search results page because it uses list.phtml too.

**EDIT

For a category page, I think you should put a 'Layout update' into the Magento admin area for the category : Catalog->Manage Categories->(select the category)->Custom Design->Layout Update. Add the following code:

```
 <reference name='product_list'>
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>auctionmodulecompany/auctionmodulename/catalog/product/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
 </reference>
```

For changing the font colours, first the bottom price, it is controlled by the CSS selector `#gridauction .current_price` in file `auction.css`.

The red price at the top is trickier. It is set by CSS that is actually placed at the end of your `<head>` section. Do you have a control panel somewhere from which you control the Google fonts or the theme font and font colour? Failing that try looking in your theme's '`head.phtml`' file or, as a bit of a hack, add in to `auction.css` the following CSS to overrule the CSS in the head.

```
.products-grid .item .price-box .regular-price .price{color: #000!important;}
```

Comment: which links do you need? the frondend web(shop) link?

Comment: www.yachtaction.se/auction/index/ --> example how we want it, and www.horloge-style.nl/weekenddeal --> our site --> can't find how to change it so we also see auction time beneath product foto

Comment: Nice site; I like your watches. In your theme's local XML try adding something like... hmmm, no, sorry, can you tell me is www.horologe-style.nl/weekenddeal a static CMS page? If it is a static CMS page, what widget (or code) are you using to put the product on the page? Or is it a category page? You want it to look like www.horologe-style.nl/auction/index, yes? It should be simple once we have all the info we need.

Comment: it is a catagory page and we want the same as yachtaction.se/auction/index Normally that's a standard option of the extension but because we've a custom template it won't show the auction option in the catalog page...proberly because it uses the wrong list.phtml?

Comment: sorry, and yes we want to show www.horologe-style.nl/auction/index page just in catalog page. If that's possible then i'll be very happy :-) And which file to change the color of the Price above photo red to black and beneath photo black to red?